# Akka Terminate Dead Letters

Tags: akka

I completed the first Akka assignment for the Coursera Reactive Programming Class (week five - binary trees).

My question is about Akka itself.

My app runs correctly, but I notice a lot of non-fatal dead letter warnings. Here is one:

```
[INFO] [01/16/2014 15:09:41.668] [PostponeSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-23] [akka://PostponeSpec/user/$c/$b/$a/$b/$a/$a/$b/$b/$a/$a] Message [akka.dispatch.sysmsg.Terminate] from Actor[akka://PostponeSpec/user/$c/$b/$a/$b/$a/$a/$b/$b/$a/$a#570299303] to Actor[akka://PostponeSpec/user/$c/$b/$a/$b/$a/$a/$b/$b/$a/$a#570299303] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I notice others have asked about this, and the official answer is that this isn't a problem, it's just verbose information that can be ignored and hidden by updating the logging settings.

I understand the advice to simply ignore this, but it still seems like a sloppy flaw on Akka's part. In this simple learning exercise, I am confident that my actors never get sent a message after they initiate a graceful shutdown. Akka should not be putting anything in the dead letter queue in these idealized circumstances. What is the justification for these dead letters? I also see it that the dead letter message isn't one that my app explicitly sends, but an internal message.

Comment: That looks like an exchange between TestKit actors to me - so not an "internal Akka" message.

Comment: To make this question more clear could you edit the title to something less general? Thanks ;)

Comment: Tough to say why this is happening without a code sample showing what you are doing. That should shed more light on why you are seeing dead letters

Comment: Which version of akka are you running?

Answer (score 1):

As someone who took the course as well,and asked questions in the course feed I recall the following: the child actor may decide to stop itself,but its parent may decide to do the same thing. At this point there's an inherent race condition between the parent's termination and the delivery of the Terminate(child) message,if the parent managed to stop itself prior to receiving the message it will end in the dead letters queue.